# cant find the translation

Tags: перевод

I have tried deepl.com, translate.google.com, translate.bing.com, translate.yandex.com, context.reverso.net

what is the translation?

"нᴇᴄʍᴏᴛᴩя нᴀ ʙᴄᴇ ʍᴏи уᴄиᴧия, ᴇᴄᴛь ᴧюди, ᴋᴏᴛᴏᴩыʍ я нᴩᴀʙᴧюᴄь."

Thank you.

Comment: Despite all my efforts, there are still people who like me.